# Number of dimensions mismatch - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm quite new to TF and i was trying to use a toy dataset from the tensorflow website with an existing model we have. The toy dataset code is as follows:

```
    inputs = tf.range(10.)[:, None]
    labels = inputs * 5. + tf.range(5.)[None, :]
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    dict(x=inputs, y=labels)).repeat().batch(2)
```

Problem is, the model expects 4 dimensions and complains with the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (2, 1)

.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:
```

Does anyone know a quick way to edit the code above to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add 2 more dimensions to make it 4 dimensional in order to fit your existing model. See https://programmerah.com/tensorflow-how-to-use-expand_dim-to-add-dimensions-20918/

Comment: Error message clearly says one of your Conv layer expecting 4D input as 4+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols)` if data_format='channels_first' or 4+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (rows, cols, channels)` if data_format='channels_last'. Add batch_size and channels to your input data example `(4, 28, 28, 3)`. Thanks!